# Efficiently sum items by type

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, list-comprehension

I have a list of items with properties `"Type"` and `"Time"` that I want to quickly sum the time for each `"Type"` and append to another list. The list looks like this:

```
Items = [{'Name': A, 'Type': 'Run', 'Time': 5},  
          {'Name': B, 'Type': 'Walk', 'Time': 15},  
          {'Name': C, 'Type': 'Drive', 'Time': 2},
          {'Name': D, 'Type': 'Walk', 'Time': 17},  
          {'Name': E, 'Type': 'Run', 'Time': 5}]
```

I want to do something that works like this:

```
Travel_Times=[("Time_Running","Time_Walking","Time_Driving")]
Run=0
Walk=0
Drive=0    

for I in Items:
    if I['Type'] == 'Run':
       Run=Run+I['Time']
    elif I['Type'] == 'Walk': 
       Walk=Walk+I['Time']           
    elif I['Type'] == 'Drive': 
       Drive=Drive+I['Time']           

Travel_Times.append((Run,Walk,Drive))
```

With `Travel_Times` finally looking like this:

```
print(Travel_Times)
[("Time_Running","Time_Walking","Time_Driving")
 (10,32,2)]
```

This seems like something that should be easy to do efficiently with either a list comprehension or something similar to `collections.Counter`, but I can't figure it out. The best way I have figured is to use a separate list comprehension for each "Type" but that requires iterating through the list repeatedly. I would appreciate any ideas on how to speed it up.

Thanks

Comment: @ roganjosh.  The actual code calculates and summarizes an Items list for about 1.1 different paths, with each having between 1 and 250 Items in it. My original solution, runs in 2860 seconds. Roganjosh's solution (with a dictionary) runs in 1285 seconds (2.2 times faster) and Eric Dumhill's solution (using Counter) runs in 899 seconds (3.2 times faster than my code).

Comment: I also tested it with a smaller subset of only 3000 paths and got nearly identical % speed improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that case is very important in Python :

- `For` isn't a valid statement
- `Travel_times` isn't the same as `Travel_Times`
- there's no `:` after `elif`
- `Travel_Times.append(...` has a leading space, which confuses Python
- `items` has one `[` too many
- `A` isn't defined

Having said that, a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) works just fine for your example :

```
from collections import Counter

time_counter = Counter()

items = [{'Name': 'A', 'Type': 'Run', 'Time': 5},  
          {'Name': 'B', 'Type': 'Walk', 'Time': 15},  
          {'Name': 'C', 'Type': 'Drive', 'Time': 2},
          {'Name': 'D', 'Type': 'Walk', 'Time': 17},  
          {'Name': 'E', 'Type': 'Run', 'Time': 5}]

for item in items:
    time_counter[item['Type']] += item['Time']

print(time_counter)
# Counter({'Walk': 32, 'Run': 10, 'Drive': 2})
```

To get a list of tuples :

```
[tuple(time_counter.keys()), tuple(time_counter.values())]
# [('Run', 'Drive', 'Walk'), (10, 2, 32)]
```

Comment: I corrected the formatting issues. I am typing this at work and didn't have the actual code or data handy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict to keep track of the total times. Using the `.get()` method, you can tally up the total times. If the key for the activity doesn't already exist, set its tally to zero and count up from there.

```
items = [{'Name': 'A', 'Type': 'Run', 'Time': 5},  
          {'Name': 'B', 'Type': 'Walk', 'Time': 15},  
          {'Name': 'C', 'Type': 'Drive', 'Time': 2},
          {'Name': 'D', 'Type': 'Walk', 'Time': 17},  
          {'Name': 'E', 'Type': 'Run', 'Time': 5}]

totals = {}

for item in items:
    totals[item['Type']] = totals.get(item['Type'], 0) + item['Time']

for k, v in totals.items():
    print("Time {}ing:\t {} mins".format(k, v))
```

Comment: This seems quite inefficient with lots of lookups

Comment: @PeterWood It was the recommended method by Raymond Hettinger in one of his keynotes. I tested it against `Counter` and it actually was marginally faster. For this particular application, I'm not sure how it performs, I will `timeit`

Comment: @PeterWood You might want to check I tested correctly. I tested `Counter` method by Eric: `10000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 µs per loop` vs my method: `100000 loops, best of 3: 5.58 µs per loop`. However, I think this is a bit artificial due to overhead of calling `Counter()`. For larger data structures, it might level out.

Comment: @PeterWood and for the `chain`/`repeat` method: `10000 loops, best of 3: 86.5 µs per loop`

Comment: Within 2 hours of posting my question I have 5 answers, a discussion about which should work better and @roganjosh even tested the solutions for performance. You guys rock!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Counter` from `collections` along with `chain` and `repeat` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
from collections import Counter

from_it = chain.from_iterable
res = Counter(from_it(repeat(d['Type'], d['Time']) for d in Items))
```

This small snippet results in a `Counter` instance containing the sums:

```
print(res)
Counter({'Drive': 2, 'Run': 10, 'Walk': 32})
```

It uses `repeat` to, obviously, repeat the `d['Type']` for `d['Time']` times and then feeds all these to `Counter` for the summation using `chain.from_iterable`.

---

If your `Items` list has many entries, you can again use `chain.from_iterable` to chain these all together:

```
res = Counter(from_it(repeat(d['Type'], d['Time']) for d in from_it(Items)))
```

This will get you a sum of all types in all the nested lists.

Comment: At least on Python 2.7, I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm not certain if something changed from `2.7` to `3.x` since I don't use `2` that much . From what I understand, it works fine in `3.x` for you, right? *Update*: Can't verify the failure in `2.7`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Enthought Canopy has me confined to 2.7 so it's not easy for me to switch and test. I need to find out what part it's unhappy about, it seems a pretty big change to give that kind of error between 2 and 3...

Comment: I think you both have different test data. Jim has his own list nested in another, while rogan just has the list of dicts :) Typo from OP

Comment: @MosesKoledoye ah, makes sense, we chose different paths to fix the unbalanced `[` :)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye nice catch! Was scratching my head there.

Comment: It fails, though, if times aren't integers - and can take a long time to execute if we have a big `Time`

Comment: Sorry about the extra [, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
# from functools import reduce # Python 3

d = reduce(lambda x, y: x + Counter({y['Type']: y['Time']}), Items, Counter())          
print(d)
# Counter({'Walk': 32, 'Run': 10, 'Drive': 2})
```

It simply builds up the `Counter` updating each `Type` using the corresponding `Time` value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief way of expressing what you'd like in one line. By the way, your list `Items` doesn't need to be double bracketed:

```
>>> Items = [{'Type': 'Run', 'Name': 'A', 'Time': 5}, 
         {'Type': 'Walk', 'Name': 'B', 'Time': 15}, 
         {'Type': 'Drive', 'Name': 'C', 'Time': 2}, 
         {'Type': 'Walk', 'Name': 'D', 'Time': 17}, 
         {'Type': 'Run', 'Name': 'E', 'Time': 5}]
>>> zip(("Time_Running","Time_Walking","Time_Driving"), (sum(d['Time'] for d in Items if d['Type'] == atype) for atype in 'Run Walk Drive'.split()))
[('Time_Running', 10), ('Time_Walking', 32), ('Time_Driving', 2)]
```

Here I zipped your output labels to a generator that calculates the sum for each of the three transportation types you have listed. For your exact output you could just use:

```
>>> [("Time_Running","Time_Walking","Time_Driving"), tuple(sum(d['Time'] for d in Items if d['Type'] == atype) for atype in 'Run Walk Drive'.split())]
[('Time_Running', 'Time_Walking', 'Time_Driving'), (10, 32, 2)]
```

Comment: @EricDuminil good point - I've updated the wording. Perhaps faster in WPM ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to abuse generators for their side effects:

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
# throw away the resulting elements, as .update does the work for us
[_ for _ in (count.update({item['Type']:item['Time']}) for item in items) if _]

>>> count
Counter({'Walk': 32, 'Run': 10, 'Drive': 2})
```

This works because `Counter.update()` returns `None`. `if None` will always evaluate `False` and throw out that element. So this generates a side effect empty list `[]` as the only memory overhead. `if False` would work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dictionary! Note that in python it is idomatic to use `snake_case` for variables and keys.

```
travel_times = {'run': 0, 'walk': 0, 'drive': 0}
for item in items:
    action, time = item['type'], item['time']
    travel_times[action] += time
```